# Custom EditText not working after setting its input type through setInputType()

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-custom-view, android-inputtype

I have created a custom `EditText`, and have its `onDraw()` function overridden. Everything was working fine (I could draw anything inside the EditText) until I wanted to change the input method for this `EditText` and have called this function:

```
setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
```

No matter when and where I call it: after it has been called, my custom `EditText` disappears, and only the original `EditText` is shown, although my overridden `onDraw()` function, and inside it, either its super function is invoked (no matter where exactly I invoke it).

I have also tried playing with Transparent colors as suggested in some posts here: 
`setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)` on the base class, and also
`paint.setColor(0x80FF0000)` for my `Paint` object in the `onDraw()` function
but they had no effect.

EDIT:
I have discovered that the problem is not lying in setting input type, but setting input type AND gravity of `EditText` simultaneously:

```
setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

If any of them is not set, my custom view is drawn as expected. Also (and what is even more strange): with `Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL` there is no problem, only with `Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL` and `Gravity.CENTER`.

It seems like these two settings are mutually exclusive. Could this be possible?

Comment: where are you calling it? ARe you calling it in the onCreate of the activity?

Comment: I am calling these setter functions in the constructor of my custom class that extends EditText (although I have tried setting one of them in constructor and setting the other from a button's onClickListener but the result was the same: my "drawings" disappeared as I clicked the button)

Comment: Thank you so much for EDIT. It saved my life.. :D

Answer (score 5):

Check your `getScrollX()` values. I bet you'll see values like 1000000 pixels. EditText translates its canvas in this weird way, so eventhough you're actually drawing on it, it's way off the visible clip.

To solve it just add the scrollX value to your drawing coordinates.

Comment: thank you! I was struggling for several hours while trying to find why adding 'numberDecimal' to input type ruined all my painting in onDraw(). Got really close by observing that clipRect() is set to some weird x translation, but it didn't click. Sometimes development for Android reminds me of living in some detective story :)

Comment: for tartar sauce god, how could you figure out that the getScrollX() is the cause?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @simekadam's answer I managed finally to fix it.
This is how I fixed it in case you didn't get it

```
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {        
    super.onDraw(canvas)
    canvas.translate(scrollX.toFloat(), 0f)
    // do your drawing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set android:digits="0123456789" in xml.But I don't know why...

Answer (score 0):

getScrollX() solved my problem

```
   @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawLine(0f+getScrollX(), 20f, 200f+getScrollX(), 30f, p);       
    }
```